# how to format string as my expectation in android?

Tags: java, android, regex, string, formatting

Suppose I have a string like that

```
String s= " %K%%m%r%";
```

Now I want to get the string formatted as

```
"k%m%r"
```

means the white spaces will be removed from the beginning and end point, if it starts or ends with % then only those % will be removed and in the middle if the % remains sequentially more than one then those will be reduced to only one %.

how can I do that?

Comment: is it always "%----% pattern in your String ?

Comment: not always, but sometimes it may be

Comment: @Reyjohn What is wrong with this, `trim and String.replace("%%","%");`

Comment: If I replace %% with % then when there is %%% I get %%, but I need only one %. And also I need to remove % from first and last position if any@NaimishViradia

Comment: then the hard way will be split your string to char array and check for consecutive "%"s . But for easy way , you can find some regular expression .

Comment: give me the solution in that easy way

Answer (score 2):

```
String pattern = "(%+)";
String exclude = "(^%*)|(%*$)";
String candidate = "%K%%%m%%%%%r%";
System.out.println(candidate.trim().replaceAll(exclude,"").replaceAll(pattern, "%"));
```

**produce:** 
K%m%r

Answer (score 1):

Here is Regex Solution,

You how to write trim logic though, And modify according to your need.

Which replace any consecutive character with single one,

```
class My
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String data=" %s%%m%%%n";
        data = data.replaceAll("([%])(\\1{1,})", "$1");
        data = data.trim();
        data = data.substring(1,data.length()-1);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide me a complete solution as my expectation using % and also removing them from first and last position if there is any?

Comment: it gives me %s%m%n but I need to remove that first % too and also the whitespaces from the beggining and end point, thanks

Comment: @Reyjohn You can give some effort also. Anyway I modified code.